# Where to put common variables for groups in Ansible

Tags: ssh, deployment, ansible

We have some scripts to help us set up VPCs with up to 6 VMs in AWS. Now I want to log in to each of these machines. For security reasons we can only access one of them via SSH and then tunnel/proxy through that to the other machines. So in our inventory we have the IP address of the SSH host (we call it *Redcarpet*) and some other hosts like *Elasticsearch*, *Mongodb* and *Worker*:

```
#inventory/hosts

[redcarpet]
57.44.113.25

[services]
10.0.1.2

[worker]
10.0.5.77
10.0.1.200

[elasticsearch]
10.0.5.30

[mongodb]
10.0.1.5
```

Now I need to tell each of the groups, EXCEPT redcarpet to use certain SSH settings. If these were applicable to all groups, I would put them in `inventory/group_vars/all.yml`, but now I will have to put them in:

- `inventory/group_vars/services.yml`
- `inventory/group_vars/worker.yml`
- `inventory/group_vars/elasticsearch.yml`
- `inventory/group_vars/mongodb.yml`

Which leads to duplication. Therefore I would like to use an `include` or `include_vars` to include one or two variables from a common file (e.g. `inventory/common.yml`). However, when I try to do this in any of the group_var files above, it does not pick up the variables. What is the best practice to use with variables that are common to multiple groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to go with the group_vars approach, I would suggest you add another group, and add the dependent groups as children to that group.

```
#inventory/hosts

[redcarpet]
57.44.113.25

[services]
10.0.1.2

[worker]
10.0.5.77
10.0.1.200

[elasticsearch]
10.0.5.30

[mongodb]
10.0.1.5

[redcarpet_deps:children]
mongodb
elasticsearch
worker
services
```

And now you can have a group_vars file called `redcarpet_deps.yml` and they should pickup the vars from there.

Comment: Oh my that's a very straightforward and simple solution indeed. I am still wondering why the includes didn't work, but this would of course solve my immediate problem.