# Ansible inventory: inheritance between groups

Tags: ansible

Is there a way I can inherit variables between groups without using `[all:vars]`

Example:

```
[GROUP_A]
server-A1 
[GROUP_A:vars]
vpc_cidr="192.10.0.0/21"

[GROUP_B]
server-B1
[GROUP_B:vars]
public_cidr="{{ vpc_cidr }}"
```

Comment: Wouldn't a meta group as a superset containing the desired variable also work?

Comment: Actually this question is not about inheriting, but referring to a fact from another host. Easily doable with [magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).

Comment: You can nest groups. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890344/where-to-put-common-variables-for-groups-in-ansible/47893834#47893834

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it with child groups, put shared vars in the parent

```
[parent_group:vars]
some_var=foo
some_other_var=bar

[parent_group:children]
GROUP_A
GROUP_B

[GROUP_A]
group_a_specific_var=foobar

[GROUP_B]
group_b_specific_var=barfoo
```